# Adding Subclass to Main Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

```
var Test = {

    Hoi : {
        test: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },

    c: function(e) {
         console.log(e);
    }
};

Test.c("hey 1");
Test.Hoi.c("hey 2");
```

I've doing some classes exercising, but I can't manage to put subclasses into a main class.

Comment: Those aren't classes.  However, your code should work fine.

Comment: you might want to make your question subject slightly more descriptive than 'little javascript issue' - that could probably describe most JS problems here!  Maybe 'problem adding subclasses to main class' or something like that

Comment: `Test.Hoi.c` doesn't

Comment: Shouldn't it be Test.Hoi.test("hey 2");

Comment: What you have are nested objects. That has nothing, whatsoever, to do with classes. And object is really just a key,value store. There is almost no magic involved. `Test.Hoi.c()` does not work because `Hoi` clearly doesn't have a property `c`, it only has the property `test`.

Answer (score 3):

`Test.Hoi.c` doesn't exist; `Test.Hoi.test` does 
use:

```
Test.Hoi.test("hey 2");
```

each dot basically digs a step deeper into the structure of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the `c` method.

```
...
Hoi : {
    test: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    },
    c: function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
...
Test.Hoi.c("hey 2");
```